# Updating MS SQL rows using @values

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-update

Is it possible to us my **existing INSERT code** and have it do the same thing but **UPDATE**?

Example would be:

```
ID  | formTitle1 | formTitle2 | formTitle3 | formTitle4
-------------------------------------------------------
20  | The Rock   | Booker     | The Vine   | Keys
```

if i wanted to update all 4 of those rows then i think i could do it like this?:

```
sql = "UPDATE formSettings " & _
      "SET (formTitle1, formTitle2, formTitle3, formTitle4) " & _
      "VALUES (@formTitle1, @formTitle2, @formTitle3, @formTitle4) " & _
      "WHERE ID = '" & theID & "'"

Dim updateCmd As New SqlCommand(sql, myCONN)
updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@formTitle1", SqlDbType.VarChar)
updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@formTitle2", SqlDbType.VarChar)
updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@formTitle3", SqlDbType.VarChar)
updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@formTitle4", SqlDbType.VarChar)

updateCmd.Parameters("@formTitle1").Value = "changed1"
updateCmd.Parameters("@formTitle2").Value = "changed2"
updateCmd.Parameters("@formTitle3").Value = "changed3"
updateCmd.Parameters("@formTitle4").Value = "changed4"

myCONN.Open()
updateCmd.ExecuteScalar()
myCONN.Close()
```

Should update to:

```
ID  | formTitle1 | formTitle2 | formTitle3 | formTitle4
-------------------------------------------------------
20  | changed1   | changed2   | changed3   | changed4
```

I know i have the wrong UPDATE syntax but i am unsure if this is even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have invalid syntax for update, it should be

```
sql = "UPDATE formSettings " & _
      "SET formTitle1 = @formTitle1, formTitle2 = @formTitle2, formTitle3 = @formTitle3, formTitle4 = @formTitle4 " & _
      "WHERE ID = @ID"
```

and parameterized also your `ID` and you will now have 5 parameters

also restructure your code into this,

- using `USING` statement
- adding exception handling

snippet,

```
Dim _sql As String = "UPDATE formSettings " & _
      "SET formTitle1 = @formTitle1, formTitle2 = @formTitle2, formTitle3 = @formTitle3, formTitle4 = @formTitle4 " & _
      "WHERE ID = @ID" 
Using conn As New SqlConnection("connectionStringHere")
    Using comm As New SqlCommand()
        With comm
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = _sql
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@formTitle1", "changed1")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@formTitle2", "changed2")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@formTitle3", "changed3")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@formTitle4", "changed4")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", theID)
        End With
        Try
            conn.Open()
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            ' do something on the error
            ' do not hide it!
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

SOURCES

- [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)
- [**Add** (*recommended to use*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyaybfa1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tbl
SET Field1 = @Value1, Field2 = @Value2
WHERE ....
```